# How to Create Arrays With Different Names Based on Some count times

Tags: ios

```
for (int i=0; i<array.count; i++)
{
    NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"array%i",i];  
    NSMutableArray *stringName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

I don't know its right or wrong i just want to create count number of times NSMutableArray Should create with different names like

the name string represent

```
name = array0
name = array1 
name = array2.....name=array10
```

I want to Create

```
NSMutableArray *array0 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
.
.
.
NSMutableArray *array10 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Like this

Comment: why you need to create n number of array?

Comment: Actually, i want to store geofence Coordinates details in array, i have number of polygons each time i want to store that details in seperate named array and saperate named GMSPath to draw multiple polygons on googlemaps

Comment: Why not use a two-dimensional array?

Comment: @Sten Can i have example

Comment: You can also manage it by NSMutableDictionary. key name will be "NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"array%i",i];" and its value   will be you polygon array.

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    for(int i=0;i<numOfSubArrays;i++){
        NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray new];
        [myArray addObject: tempArray];
    }

    [myArray[0] addObject:object00]; 
    [myArray[0] addObject:object01];
    .
    . 
    [myArray[1] addObject:object10];
    [myArray[1] addObject:object11];
    //etc
   //myArray[1][1] is object11
```